# How to recreate AngularJS service for testing purposes?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-service

I would like to test myService initialisation which could be different depends on conditions:

```
service('myService', function(internalService){
   if(internalService.param){ init1(); }
   else { init2(); }

   //...
});
```

I can mock `internalService`, but how to recreate `myService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are instantiated by the injector (`inject(...)`) after the configuration phase. To test your initialization, all you need to do is setup differently in each tests. That is, rather than instantiating your service in a `beforeEach` block, do it in the test.

For instance, you could test the side effects of instantiating with `init1` by mocking the `internalService` to have `param: true`

```
describe('Unit: myService', function() {
  it('should perform init1 if internalService.param', function() {
    var mockInternalService = {
      param: true,
    };

    // config phase (mocking)
    module('app', function($provide) {
      $provide.constant('internalService', mockInternalService);
    });

    inject(function($injector) {
      myService = $injector.get('myService');

      // assert side effects from init1();
    });
  });
});
```

To test the side effects of `init2`, just mock the `internalService` to `param: false`

```
  it('should perform init2 if !internalService.param', function() {
    var mockInternalService = {
      param: false,
    };

    // config phase (mocking)
    module('app', function($provide) {
      $provide.constant('internalService', mockInternalService);
    });

    inject(function($injector) {
      myService = $injector.get('myService');

      // assert side effects from init2();
    });
  });
```

---

EDIT: Of course, if you want to make *multiple* tests for each configuration, you can create two `describe` blocks with different `beforeEach`.

```
  describe('Unit: myService', function() {
    var myService;

    describe('When instantiated with `init1`', function() {
      beforeEach(config(true));
      beforeEach(inject(injections));

      it('should do X');
    });

    describe('When instantiated with `init2`', function() {
      beforeEach(config(false));
      beforeEach(inject(injections));

      it('should do Y');
    });

    function config(param) {
       return function() { 
         var mockInternalService = {
           param: param,
         };

         // config phase (mocking)
         module('app', function($provide) {
           $provide.constant('internalService', mockInternalService);
         });
      };
    }

    function injections($injector) {
      myService = $injector.get('myService');
    }
  });
```

Comment: does it mean that for each "it" I'll have to create separate module definition?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from creating a describe block with a beforeEach for both setups. I'll update my answer.

Comment: "a describe block with a beforeEach" - yes, that's what I made. thank you for detailed answer!